# mysql query issue while data recieving

Tags: mysql, sql

### Sql Query to retrieve data using table ##

I need query to get the count of participants in each level .

Note: participant who is in level 4 should not be in other levels ex: Level 3,2,1

### Table :

```
ID   Level    date

38  1 06 -05
38  2 08 -05
38  3 12 -05
38  4 13 -05 
39  1 13 -05
39  2 13 -05
40  1 12 -05
```

Needed Output:

```
Count  Level
 1      1
 1      2
 0      3
 1      4
```

Comment: I have just changed the question please look in to it..

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/053447/10  Check answer here ..!

Answer (score 0):

You can define an artadditional table (or create a subquery) which would return the 30 rows
e.g

```
(select now() as d
union
select date_sub(now(), interval 1 day) as d
union
select date_sub(now(), interval 2 day) as d
union
...
select date_sub(now(), interval 29 day) as d) all_dates_source
```

Then you can LEFT JOIN your query result to the all_dates_source

```
SELECT i,
       Logindate2,
       ifnull(Logindate2,0, Logins2) as Logins2
FROM (...) all_dates_source
   LEFT JOIN (yourQueryHere) sourceQuery 
        on all_dates_source.d=sourceQuery.Logindate2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(t2.ppt) as count,t1.Level as level
FROM courselevel t1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ppt,MAX(Level) as Level
FROM courselevel
GROUP BY ppt ) t2 on t1.ppt=t2.ppt and t1.Level=t2.Level
GROUP BY t1.Level
```